# Function inverse tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

Is there a way to find the inverse of neural network representation of a function in tensorflow v1? I require this to find the optimal function in an optimization problem that I am solving.

To be precise, the optimal function is found by minimizing the error computed as L2 norm of difference between the approximated optimal function C* (coded as a neural network object), and inverse of a value function V* (coded as another neural network object).

My problem is that I do not know how to write inverse of V* in tensorflow, as I cannot find something like `tf.inverse()`.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am misunderstanding the situation, I believe that it is impossible to do this in a generalized way. Many functions do not have a perfect inverse. For a simple example, imagine a `square(x)` function that computes x<sup>2</sup>. You might think that the inverse is `sqrt(y)`, but in reality the "correct" result could be either `sqrt(y)` or `-sqrt(y)`, with no way of telling which is correct.

Similarly, with most neural networks I imagine it would be impossible to find the "true" mathematical inverse. There are architectures that attempt to train a neural net and its inverse simultaneously (autoencoders and BiGAN/ALI come to mind), and for some nets it might be possible to train an inverse empirically, but these can have extremely varying levels of accuracy that depend heavily on many factors.

Depending on how much control you have over V*, you might be able to design it in such a way that it is mathematically invertible (and then you would have to manually code the inverse), or you might be able to make it a simpler model that is not based on a neural net. However, if V* is an arbitrary preexisting net, then you're probably out of luck.

Further reading:

- [SO: local inverse of a neural network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15131713/2846923)
- [AI.SE: Can we get the inverse of the function that a neural network represents?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17566/27092)